# How to switch execution based on NSTimer every 30 seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, timer

```
let duration = 10
self.configureTimer(startTime: Date(), duration: duration)
self.countdownTimer.start()
```

With the above code, how to switch execution every 30 seconds between 2 methods as below:

```
func first30Seconds() { } 
func next30Seconds() { }
```

basically I'm trying to toggle between the above two methods `first30Seconds` and `next30Seconds` for every 30 seconds that the timer is ticking. Would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: How often is your timer ticking?  Every 10 seconds?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is ticking once per second. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of a timer instance with:

```
var timer: Timer!
```

Then update both functions to call the other after 30 seconds:

```
func first30Seconds() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(second30Seconds), userInfo:nil, repeats: false)
    // Other code...
} 
func second30Seconds() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(first30Seconds), userInfo:nil, repeats: false)
    // Other code...
}
```